# Passing foreign-key to server with backbone.js

Tags: django, backbone.js, foreign-keys

I have a server which is using django and tastypie and a client web based app using backbone.js, I can read the data ok but the problem comes when I try to add new model with foreign-keys and then sync.

So I figured the easiest way is to call the collection.create which automatically syncs with the server. If I do that on a table that has no foreign-keys it works fine. BUT, when I have a model that has relationship on the server database, I do not know how I'm suppose to specify the foreign-key.

The model foreign key comes originally in this format: `/api/v1/porttype/4/`

If I try building a string like that, I get a 404 error, if I try to send in just a int, I get a 404 error.

I'm not really sure what the server expects. I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue... I'm a bit lost right now. So far I do something like this:

```
collection.create([ { 'project': '/api/v1/porttype/4/', 'name': 'test' } ]);
```

`project` in this case would be the foreign key.

EDIT: The stacktrace I get back from my server:

```
{"error_message": "", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last)n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 397, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1165, in post_list\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1774, in obj_create\n    bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 698, in full_hydrate\n    value = field_object.hydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/fields.py\", line 636, in hydrate\n    value = super(ToOneField, self).hydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/fields.py\", line 154, in hydrate\n    elif self.attribute and getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute, None)n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 301, in __get__\n    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist\n\nDoesNotExist\n"}
```

It seems like it won't recognize it... And from what I have searched for this django error, it seems to happen you do not send in a non-null field when adding, but not sure

Help!

Comment: It would help to see your Models and Resources.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the foreign key in the model, which is then sent over in the JSON payload? For example:

Do not pass in references this way:

```
collection.create([ { 'project': '/api/v1/porttype/4/', 'name': 'test'} ]);
```

Instead, you just process the request on the server side as another parameter.

On the backbone side of things I would change the above to this:

```
collection.create([ { 'project_id': 4, 'name': 'test'} ]);
```

Where project_id is the foreign_key reference to the project table

Then, in your controller code you need to have your ORM handle the rest. I leave that as an exercise to the reader :-)

Comment: Well 'project' in this case is the foreign key, I'm trying to send it in the same format I'm getting from the server which is '/api/v1/porttype/4/', but I get an error back... I'm pasting the stacktrace I get from my server in my question

Comment: I also tried sending in just the int, as mentioned above, but still get the same error

Comment: You should not be passing in a full URI, only an integer reference ID. See the edit to my own answer

Comment: I didn't manage to solve this yet, but, I found that calling 'save' on a new model instead of 'create' on the collection, and using 'project': {'pk':4} works.